# HighChart Tooltip different suffix values

Tags: highcharts, tooltip, suffix

Hi i have to show the rank of students in highchart (spider web chart). in y axis i have to added different suffix values for different ranks (ie 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th.. 100th). can anyone help me on this.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `formatter` function for tooltip:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }],
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            switch (this.x) {
                case 1:
                    return 1 + 'st'
                case 2:
                    return 2 + 'nd'
                case 3:
                    return 3 + 'rd'
                default:
                    return this.x + 'th'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g48mszj9/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter